# Use external sqlite database in application

Tags: android, sqlite

Suppose in my phone's internal memory I have a folder named kc and in that kc folder I have a sqlite bd named local.db ,  now I need to connect to that database by my app and need to run a query like select name from survey_master show me the results in a toast in main activity onCreate method. How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to know how to open a database? Have you tried [openDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29)?

Comment: First by creating a Toast. Come back once it's done

Comment: First copy the db into the proper folder. Then use it.

Comment: @CL: Yes I've tried openDatabase... Funkystein: did you mean the 'data/data/packagename/databases/' path as proper folder, I need that database after some work... if I put my database in application folder I can not copy that.... I had made this previously by using Oracle MAF... is there any way to use external SQLite JDBC in the Android Studio and use it to call Externally....

Answer (score 0):

create your database and named it as like as **myDB.sqlite**
and put it into your app assets folder.

**DB-Manager class**

```
public class AppsDatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    private String DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/yourFolderName";
    private static String DB_NAME = "myDB.sqlite";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Context context;

    public AppsDatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
        this.context = context;

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public boolean initializeDatabase() {
        if (DB_PATH == null)
            return false;

        try {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + "/" + DB_NAME, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE
                            | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + "/" + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        new File(outFileName).createNewFile();
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

}
```

**In your Activity:**

```
AppsDatabaseManager dbManager = new AppsDatabaseManager(this);

if( dbManager.initializeDatabase() ){
    //
}
```

**Give the permission in manifesto:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Download my full example: [GitRepo](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/ExternalDataBase)

Comment: you can download my example from git . https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/ExternalDataBase